# How to store null value into array

Tags: php

$array is this.First two index has null value.I want this null to be stored in array of $value. how to do this

```
Array
    (
        [ew-language__en] => 
        [ew-language__en__0__phrase__locale] => 
        [ew-language__en__1__phrase__use_system_locale] => 1
        [ew-language__en__2__phrase__decimal_point] => .
        [ew-language__en__3__phrase__thousands_sep] => ,
        [ew-language__en__4__phrase__mon_decimal_point] => .
        [ew-language__en__5__phrase__mon_thousands_sep] => ,
        [ew-language__en__6__phrase__currency_symbol] => $
        [ew-language__en__7__phrase__positive_sign] => 
        [ew-language__en__8__phrase__negative_sign] => -
        [ew-language__en__9__phrase__frac_digits] => 2
        [ew-language__en__10__phrase__p_cs_precedes] => 1
        [ew-language__en__11__phrase__p_sep_by_space] => 0
        [ew-language__en__12__phrase__n_cs_precedes] => 1
        [ew-language__en__13__phrase__n_sep_by_space] => 0
        [ew-language__en__14__phrase__p_sign_posn] => 3
        [ew-language__en__15__phrase__n_sign_posn] => 3
        [ew-language__en__16__phrase__time_zone] => US/Pacific
        [submit] => SAVE VALUE INTO XML FILE
    )

foreach ($array as $key => $value)
                 {//some code}
```

i want this $value to include null values also

Comment: simply you can do like [ew-language__en__0__phrase__locale] => null,

Comment: this array is getting values dynamically from xml file where value=" " it displays like this i can't do it like this.

Comment: Then you can use xml property to set null value in xml and then you can bind here , like <PropName xsi:nil="true">  Reference here : http://docs.intersystems.com/ens20121/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=GXMLPROJ_nulls_etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally, like this:

```
Array(
    "[ew-language__en]" => null
)
```

Now, you have just mentioned that you are getting these values dynamically from xml file where `value=" "`. You can then do:

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    if ($value == "" || ctype_space($value) ) {
        $array[$key] = null;
    }
}
```

If the `array[key]` is empty or only has whitespace, it will be converted to `null`.

Ref: [ctype_space](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-space.php)

Comment: this array is getting values dynamically from xml file where value=" " it displays like this i can't do it like this.

Comment: Given this new information, Helping Hands has good solution for XML

Comment: @Rozeena Here is the exact function you can use

Answer (score 1):

Use a loop then -

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value)
{
    if(check_condition_to_set_null) $array[$key] = null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're puling files dynamically from an XML file, Drake's answer won't work as it treats the value of the key as the string literal "null".  Instead, what you can do, is create a string literal then replace it with a null when you load the array.

In your XML:

```
<ew-language__en__0__phrase__locale>NULL</ew-language__en__0__phrase__locale>
```

In your PHP, when you load the array:

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
if ($array[$key] == "NULL") {
$array[$key] = null;
}
}
```

Comment: See, we didn't know this was even related to XML until the comments ;)

Comment: @Drakes Yep, nothing against you.  Yours is the simplest solution :)